# Overwriting Core Shipping Block

Tags: blocks

Im working on a Magento job and its been a while since I have dabbled in the dark arts. Im currently writing a small bit of script that will override the shipping methods on the checkout screen. You will have to excuse any mediocrity in my code as I said its been a while.

So I have two files:

**app/code/local/ClarkStudios/Shipmentfilter/etc/config.xml**

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_shipping_method_available>ClarkStudios_Shipmentfilter_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_available>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

**app/code/local/ClarkStudios/Shipmentfilter/Block/Onepage/Shipping/Method/Available.php**

```
class ClarkStudios_Shipmentfilter_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available
{
    public function getShippingRates()
    {
        die('HAHAHAHAHAH!');

         $rates = parent::getShippingRates();

         $two_kg_array = array('AU','US','CA','BR','VE'); 
         $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
         $shipping_country = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountry(); 
         $weight = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getWeight(); 
         if( in_array( $shipping_country, $two_kg_array ) && $weight > 2 ) {
            $rates = array();
         }

         if( !in_array( $shipping_country, $two_kg_array ) && $weight > 30 ) {
            $rates = array();
         }


        return $rates;
    }
}
```

I cant seem to get the die to fire which says that Magento is not recognising my block rewrite. I have probably done something fundamentally wrong here but a hand held in the right direction would be much appreciated.

I should probably point out that I am trying to change what shipping methods appear on the One Page Checkout page based on the weight of the cart. For starters I just want it to fire the die function so I know its working. I have flushed the cache also.

Comment: Did you create /app/etc/modules/ClarkStudios_Shipmentfilter.xml?

Comment: Thats a negative!

Comment: Also is that the entire content of your config.xml or just a section?

Comment: That is the code in its entirety. I'm probably way off here. With the module xml is there anything special that needs to go in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your config.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ClarkStudios_Shipmentfilter>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </ClarkStudios_Shipmentfilter>
    </modules>
    <global>
      <blocks>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_shipping_method_available>ClarkStudios_Shipmentfilter_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_available>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
     </blocks>
   </global>
</config>
```

Create /app/etc/modules/ClarkStudios_Shipmentfilter.xml with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ClarkStudios_Shipmentfilter>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </ClarkStudios_Shipmentfilter>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Ah that'll do it cheers dude!